# svn checkout specific version of select components

Tags: svn

I have read-only access to my company's svn repository for a product we develop and I'd like to check out components and look at them while I study c++.

How do I checkout the same version for the components I want? For example when we released version 4.1.22.18 I want that version of some components.

I did this

```
svn co https://url/svn/division1/product/component1/tags/4.1.22.18/
```

and it seemed to do what I think I want for the first component.

But the attempt on the second component gave me a message and failed.

```
svn co https://url/svn/division1/product/component2/tags/4.1.22.18/

svn: '4.1.22.18' is already a working copy for a different URL
```

The directory structure looks something like this:

```
https://url/svn/division1/product/component1
branches/
shelves/
tags/
trunk/

https://url/svn/division1/product/component2
branches/
shelves/
tags/
trunk/

https://url/svn/division1/product/component3
branches/
shelves/
tags/
trunk/
```

I want to make sure I'm looking at the same version from each component that
matches a released version of the product.
For example:

```
branches: has a 1.2.3.0-stable folder.  
tags: has a differently named set of folders/numbers, but I know which folder corresponds to the 1.2.3.0-stable branch version. 
trunk: does not have the different folder versions lik
e branches and tags, just the various artifacts.  Like setup.sh, make_rpm.sh, scripts, etc.
```

At some point I will want to build some of this code. Checking in code seems a long way off.

Linux

svn version 1.6.11

Thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, upgrade your ancient Subversion 1.6 client to version 1.9.

The problem is that you are trying to checkout different components to the same working copy. Checkout each component's tag to a separate working copy, e.g.

`svn co https://url/svn/division1/product/component1/tags/4.1.22.18/ component1`

`svn co https://url/svn/division1/product/component2/tags/4.1.22.18/ component2`

Or [configure a sparse working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) instead.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank-you.